# Save tensor as JPEG image - Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, tensorflow, tensor

I have a function that returns me a variable called **layer** - images in the format:

```
<tf.Tensor 'Conv2D_1:0' shape=(?, 16, 16, 1) dtype=float32>
```

I need to save these image in .jpeg.

So far I've thought of doing this:

```
# Reshape into tf.image.encode_jpeg format
images = tf.reshape(tf.cast(layer, tf.uint8), [16, 16, 1])

# Encode
images_encode = tf.image.encode_jpeg(images)

# Create a files name
fname = tf.constant('datetime.now() + ".jpeg"')

# Write files
fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, images_encode)

train_batch_size = 300
```

And in session = tf.Session ()

```
# That means it will only scroll through my 300 images...
x_batch, y_true_batch = next_batch_size(train_batch_size)

feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_true_batch}

result = session.run(fwrite, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 76800 values, but the requested shape has 256
    [[Node: Reshape_7 = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast_7, Reshape_7/shape)]]
```

My placeholders are:

```
# Placeholder variable for the input images
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size_flat], name='x')

# Reshape 'x'
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, img_size, img_size, num_channels])

# Placeholder variable for the true labels associated with the images
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
```

Any idea how to solve this problem, or some other methodology that I could apply to save the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a batch size of 76800 / 256 = 300

The reshape function is trying to reshape the whole batch into a `(16,16,1)` tensor: it's impossible.

If you want to save a single image, you have two choices:

1. Extract the first element of the batch `tf.reshape(tf.cast(layer[0], tf.uint8), [16, 16, 1])`
2. Set the batch size to 1

If instead, you want to save the whole batch of images, you have to loop over the batch (using [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn)) and encode the image singularly (because tf.image.encode_jpeg works on single images). Then, from python, extract every encoded images and save it to the disk.

Comment: Thanks! I tested save  a single image, it worked, but it's all black, any idea to fix it?

Comment: Don't use `tf.cast` but instead use tf.image.convert_image_dtype (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype). tf.cast brutally casts the value from a type to another (you're using float images that are in the 0,1 range, usually), you instead need to scale them up to 0.255. You can use convert_image_dtype or doing the scaling manually and then use tf.cast

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.